# Problems with sorting in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, partials

I'm trying to implement a sorting functionality in one of my tables. I'm using this documentation as reference --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-sorting

I've managed to load the table with the rows and I can change the order by applying different values in the variable sortOrder (*I mean hardcoded*)

I have a problem when I try to click in the column headers (with the anchor tag).
Fo example when I click in the column header **Nombre**, the **sortOrder** variable should change.

```
<a asp-page="/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel?Id=@Model.CursoId" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort">
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].Nombre)</a>
```

[image: Table with headers showing the problem]

But I'm not receiving the get parameter **nameSort** only the **Id**. According the doc, it should be appending the sortOrder too with **asp-route-sortOrder** attribute.

I tried removing the attribute **asp-route-sortOrder** and generate the url with the get parameters in the URL -->

```
 asp-page="/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel?Id=@Model.CursoId&sortOrder=@Model.NameSort"
```

But I'm still getting null there.
Maybe it has something to do with the partial. It is returning the table as a partial, maybe I'm losing the reference of the variable there.

**RegisteredUsers.cshtml**

```
@page
@model Administracion.Capacitaciones.InscriptosPartialModel
@{
}
<div id="inscriptos"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
    $('#inscriptos')
    .load('/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel/InscriptosPartial?Id=' + cursoId, function () {
   // I have some UI events here, ommiting them for simplicity
}
</script>
```

**InscriptosPartialModel.cshtml.cs**  *(path --> Administracion\Capacitaciones\InscriptosPartialModel.cshtml.cs)*

```
public class InscriptosPartialModel : PageModel
{
    public List<UsuarioInscriptoCursoModel> Alumnos { get; set; }
    public string NameSort { get; set; }
    public string DniSort { get; set; }

    public string _sortOrder { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<UsuarioInscriptoCursoModel> AlumnosIQ { get; set; }

    private IInscripcionRegistroCursoRepository ircRepo;

    private ICursoRepository _cursoRepo;


    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    public string NombreCurso { get; set; }

    public InscriptosPartialModel(
        IInscripcionRegistroCursoRepository inscripcionRegistroCursoRepository,
         ICursoRepository cursoRepository)
    {
        ircRepo = inscripcionRegistroCursoRepository;
        _cursoRepo = cursoRepository;
    }

    public void OnGet(int Id, string sortOrder)
    {
        CursoId = Id;
        NombreCurso = _cursoRepo.GetById(Id).Nombre;

        NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        DniSort = sortOrder == "dni" ? "dni_desc" : "dni";

        _sortOrder = sortOrder;

    }
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> OnGetInscriptosPartialAsync(int Id)
    {
        AlumnosIQ = ircRepo.GetAlumnosByCursoId(Id, _sortOrder);
        if (AlumnosIQ.Count() > 0)
        {
            Alumnos = await AlumnosIQ.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

            return Partial("_InscriptosTable", this);
        }
        else
        {
            return Partial("_EmptyData");
        }

    }
}
```

**_InscriptosTable.cshtml**

```
@using Models
@model InscriptosPartialModel

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="table_header">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel?Id=@Model.CursoId" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].Nombre)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].Apellido)</th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel?Id=@Model.CursoId" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.DniSort">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].Dni)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].ModulosInscripto.NombreModulo)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].Asistencia)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alumnos[0].Calificacion)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var alumno in Model.Alumnos)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           data-alumno="@alumno.Id"
                           data-modulo="@alumno.ModulosInscripto.ModuloId"
                           name="select-@alumno.Dni"
                           @(alumno.CumpleAsistencia() ? "disabled" : "") />
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => alumno.Nombre)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => alumno.Apellido)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => alumno.Dni)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => alumno.ModulosInscripto.NombreModulo)</td>
                <td>
                    @{
                        var encuentros = alumno.Asistencia + " / " + alumno.CantidadEncuentros;
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => encuentros)
                    }
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => alumno.Calificacion)</td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary button_lenga_primary"
                            id="desuscribirBtn"
                            data-mod="@alumno.ModulosInscripto.ModuloId"
                            data-alu="@alumno.Id"
                            data-dni="@alumno.Dni"
                            data-namemod="@alumno.ModulosInscripto.NombreModulo"
                            data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#desuscribir-modal">
                        Quitar
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**InscripcionRegistroCursoRepository.cs**

```
public class InscripcionRegistroCursoRepository : GenericRepository<InscripcionRegistroCurso>, IInscripcionRegistroCursoRepository
    {
        public InscripcionRegistroCursoRepository(LengaContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public IQueryable<UsuarioInscriptoCursoModel> GetAlumnosByCursoId(int CursoId, string sortOrder)
        {
            var inscripciones = context.Inscripciones
                .Where(row => row.InscripcionRegistroCursoId == CursoId);

            var query = (from inscripcion in inscripciones
                         join alumno in context.Alumnos on inscripcion.AlumnoId equals alumno.AlumnoId
                         join usuario in context.UsuariosExternos on alumno.AlumnoId equals usuario.AlumnoId
                         select new UsuarioInscriptoCursoModel
                         {
                             Nombre = usuario.Nombre,
                             Apellido = usuario.Apellido,
                             Dni = usuario.Dni,
                             Id = usuario.AlumnoId,
                             ModulosInscripto = inscripcion.Modulo,
                             Asistencia = inscripcion.Asistencia,
                             Calificacion = inscripcion.Calificacion,
                             CantidadEncuentros = inscripcion.Modulo.Encuentros
                         })
                             .Distinct();

            switch (sortOrder) {
                case "name_desc":
                    query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.Nombre);
                    break;
                case "dni":
                    query = query.OrderBy(a => a.Dni);
                    break;
                case "dni_desc":
                    query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.Dni);
                    break;
                default:
                    query = query.OrderBy(a => a.Nombre);
                    break;
            }
            return query;
        }
}
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,when you use

```
$('#inscriptos')
    .load('/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel/InscriptosPartial?Id=' + cursoId, function () {
   // I have some UI events here, ommiting them for simplicity
}
```

in your RegisteredUsers.cshtml,it will go to `OnGet(int Id, string sortOrder)`,and since `NameSort` is `""`,the `NameSort` will be set to `name_desc`.

And then I try to use

```
<a asp-route-Id="@Model.CursoId" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort">
```

to pass Id and sortOrder to `OnGet(int Id, string sortOrder)`,and I can get the value of Id and sortOrder in `OnGet(int Id, string sortOrder)`.Since sortOrder is not `""`,so "NameSort" will be set to `""` with `NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";` this time.

So your `sortOrder` is null may because it is after you pass `sortOrder`(which is not null) to `OnGet`,and then `OnGet` set `sortOrder` to `""`.

Comment: I edited the code, RegisteredUsers has a different model which is InscriptosPartialModel.cshtml.cs not RegisteredUsers.cshtml.cs. (second chunk of code in the question)
As you can see I have the OnGet handler but I'm not getting the params.
I debugged it and I'm not getting any of the parameters (Id or sortOrder) with the attribute asp-route-Id or asp-route-sortOrder.
I'm thinking maybe it is something to do with the table, which is a partial and it is supposed to return the id and sort-order.

Comment: Can you share your url after you click `<a asp-page="/Administracion/Capacitaciones/InscriptosPartialModel?Id=@Model.CursoId" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort">`?